# JSON Serialization in asp.net mvc webapi2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, web-services

I'm working on a project that involves a asp.net mvc webapi2. And i'm freaking out with this.
I save data into my database, and it saves well. But when I want to show it in a mobile device, only some lines of the information pass to the mobile application. Here is a example of how my JSON object should be:

```
{
Refeicoes: [1]
  0:  {
    LinhasRefeicao: [1]
     0:  {
      Alimentos: {
       Id: "IS002"
       Nome: "Não Alcoólicas, Água mineral natural gaseificada, "Pizões-Moura""
      }-
    Id: 1055
    AlimentoId: "IS002"
    Quant: 1
    RefeicaoId: 1022
         }-
        -
 Id: 1022
 DiarioId: 1012
 TipoRefeicaoId: 1
 DataRefeicao: "2014-11-10T16:37:00"
}-
-
Id: 1012
UserId: 2
DataDiario: "2014-11-10T00:00:00"
}
```

Sometimes, this works. I receive a JSON just like this. But if i insert a new object into the database, the JSON object of that last insert is like this one:

```
Refeicoes: [1]
 0:  {
  LinhasRefeicao: [2]
   0:  {
    Alimentos: {
     Id: "IS002"
     Nome: "Não Alcoólicas, Água mineral natural gaseificada, "Pizões-Moura""
    }-
   Id: 1055
   AlimentoId: "IS002"
   Quant: 1
   RefeicaoId: 1022
  }-
   1:  {
    Id: 1056
    AlimentoId: "IS474"
    Quant: 1
    RefeicaoId: 1022
    Alimentos: null
   }-
   -
  Id: 1022
  DiarioId: 1012
  TipoRefeicaoId: 1
  DataRefeicao: "2014-11-10T16:37:00"
 }-
-
Id: 1012
UserId: 2
DataDiario: "2014-11-10T00:00:00"
}
```

The problem here is that Alimentos comes null on recent inserts. On older information it displays correctly. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: It is likely that it is nothing to do with the JSON serialisation and that nulls are getting inserted into the database.

Comment: @BenRobinson, i have that part covered. I keep checking that. And they save into the database. And like i said in the question, this problem only comes with recent data inserted in the database, not the oldest info.